# ExtUtils::MakeMaker custom target

Tags: perl, makemaker

Is there a way to have a custom Makefile target to be generated by ExtUtils::MakeMaker? Say, I'd like to do some specific things that only a developer is interested in, like running pod and regression tests; I can use env variables for that but that's a bit unwieldy to remember things like that. Being able to run something like `make devtest` instead would be mighty handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Regression Testing with ExtUtils::MakeMaker

[By default](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.88/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm#make_test), MakeMaker makefiles come with a `test` target which runs all of the regression tests in `test.pl` in the current directory as well as all files matching `glob("t/*.t")` when you run `make test`. Your typical usage should be:

```
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
make install
```

You can define your own `make` targets, there's some information about the variables you can set in the [CPAN documentation for the module](https://metacpan.org/release/ExtUtils-MakeMaker) as well as the manpage.

This is the example from the CPAN article:

```
sub MY::postamble {
    return <<'MAKE_FRAG';
    $(MYEXTLIB): sdbm/Makefile
    cd sdbm && $(MAKE) all
    MAKE_FRAG
}
```

Comment: I've read the CPAN doc for MakeMaker, it's extremely vague on how to do this.

Comment: Not sure where exactly you've seen the information on how to define custom make targets in MakeMaker docs; please clarify.

Comment: @AlexTokarev I've added the example of a custom target [from here](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs2041/doc/perldoc-html-5.10.0/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.html#Overriding-MakeMaker-Methods) to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that should work! That paragraph is really tiny, no wonder I overlooked it.